# Issue with using strtotime on dd/mm/YYYY format

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to find the difference between 2 dates. However I'm stuck at the first hurdle with converting my date to a UNIX code.

Here is what I am trying:

```
    $endTimeStamp = strtotime(get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'wedding_date', true ));
```

It returns nothing, however, if I just do:

```
echo get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'wedding_date', true );
```

I get the following date: 26/12/2015 (i.e. 26th December 2015)

Is there a reason my strtotime() function isn't working with this date?

Comment: The issue here is that you haven't read the [PHP Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php). A `/` separator identifies the date as __US__ format (`mm/dd/yyyy`). A `-` separator identifies the date as __European__ format (`dd-mm-yyyy`).

Comment: Problem with `strtotime()` -> RTM about strtotime()

Comment: @MarkBaker thanks Mark, now my issue is that I don't understand the PHP Docs - How do I convert my date to a format that strtotime() understands?

Comment: don't use strtotime, then, use `date_create_from_format()` which lets you specify the input format. it's more efficient than strtotime, since you don't waste a ton of cpu cycles testing all kinds of possibly wrong formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

> However I'm stuck at the first hurdle with converting my date to a UNIX code.

**Solution:**

To get unix timestamp you can do something like this:

```
$unixdatetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', get_post_meta( $the_query->post->ID, 'wedding_date', true ))->getTimestamp();
echo $unixdatetime;
```